# Flask response streaming Minio object

Tags: flask, minio

I would like to develop an API with Flask to stream a Minio object back to the API caller.

Minio `get_object` response requires close call explicitly (https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/developers/python/API.html#get_object)

```
# Get data of an object.
try:
    response = client.get_object("my-bucket", "my-object")
    # Read data from response.
finally:
    response.close()
    response.release_conn()
```

My question: How could I achieve this connection release when I want to stream this response to Flask response?

In the following implementaion, the API caller won't get any content from Minio response

```
    try:
        response = minio_client.get_object(bucket, object)
        return app.response_class(response.stream(), status=response.status, headers=response.getheaders().items())
    finally:
        response.close()
        response.release_conn()
```